# 3d perspective viewing

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, perspective

I am trying to mess around with rendering things in 3d. I want to make it so that if you are looking straight at a building, you see the front. If you walk to the side and turn you will see both the front and side walls, but they will be distorted. And finally when you move more and turn more you will see the side wall, but not distorted.

How is this possible? If possible I would like a solution in OpenGl or something I can run in Java, however I can be flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [Java 3D](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.5.1-oth-JPR), I used it a couple of years ago and Iliked it a lot :)

[Here's a site](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1998/jw-12-media.html) with information about Java 3D.

[A nice tutorial....](http://www.java3d.org/tutorial.html)

[A longer, more complete, tutorial....](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/)

Actually, if my memory serves me correctly, Java 3D was worked on by a few of the people who worked on OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection and http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/jogl/perspectiveProjection.html

another link that looks good: http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-3:-3D-transformation-and-projection.html